# @Cacheable And @CachePut on the same method with opposite condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache

Is it possible to use `@CachePut` and `@Cacheable` in conjonction on the same method?

```
@CachePut(value ="cacheName", key = "#id", condition="#cachedData==false")
@Cacheable(value ="cacheName", key = "#id", condition="#cachedData==true")
public Foo doSomthing(String id, boolean cachedData){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `@Caching` to group multiple caching annotations to implement a customised logic.

Maybe something like:

```java
@Caching(
            put= { @CachePut(value="cacheName", key="#id", condition="#cachedData==false") },
            cacheable = { @Cacheable(value ="cacheName", key="#id", condition="#cachedData==true") }
)
public Foo doSomething(String id, boolean cachedData){...}
```